# Active Model Serializer transform all dates to seconds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-model-serializers

I need to convert all dates that get returned by my api into Unix date format (seconds). Individually is easy enough...

```
class ChimichangaSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :updated_at,

  def updated_at
    object.updated_at.to_i
  end
end
```

But since I have to do it for everything, that way lies errors and madness. How can I achieve this functionality for all of them?

Comment: Is this for all `updated_at` fields or for a bunch of otherwise unrelated fields?

Comment: All fields that have a date in them. Currently, I have 5 on several different models.

As a bonus, the same thing in reverse for input. Currently, I'm manually converting each one as it comes in.

Comment: You could subclass ActiveModel::Serializer and introduce your own `attributes` method that takes options like `:as_integer` or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing your comment regarding input conversion as well, I think you could override the getter and setter methods for those fields if you're not using them in any other form. Maybe something along these lines would help.

It's important to note that this will affect not only the field's serialization. If you want to keep normal behaviour for those fields, I'd go with Tadman's advise.

```
# with_unix_time.rb
module WithUnixTime
  # These methods lack error handling
  def to_unix_time(*fields)
    fields.each do |field|

      # Override getter.
      define_method field do
        self[field].to_i
      end

      # Override setter
      define_method "#{field}=" do |value|
        self[field] = Time.at(value)
      end

      # Convenience method to retrieve the original DateTime type
      define_method "raw_#{field}" do
        self[field]
      end
    end
  end
end

# chimichanga.rb
class Chimichanga < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend WithUnixTime
  to_unix_time :time_to_kill, :time_for_joke
end
```

Comment: Just to let you know, so you don't feel like you're hanging, I'm going to try this out and see how it goes, but since it's currently functional in a way that doesn't scale, it won't be until after my next deadline in a week or so, so I won't be picking a best answer right away.

Comment: @TiggerToo  no problem at all

Answer (score 2):

Add the following:

`app/config/initializers/time_with_zone.rb`

```
class ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
  def as_json(options = {})
    to_i
  end
end
```

this will override the default behaviour for all your timestamps when converted into json.

Comment: really use-full one, save my day